# How can I apply a load to an object in Autodesk fusion 360 with python API

Tags: python, fusion360

I want to apply a load to an object in fusion 360.
To make it fully automatically, I want to use python API.
HOW can I do it?

I tried to ask chat gpt to create a code, but it didn't work.
I have to make it fully automatically to do my project. please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.